# Get parent of current directory from Python script

Tags: python, sys, sys.path

I want to get the parent of current directory from Python script. For example I launch the script from `/home/kristina/desire-directory/scripts` the desire path in this case is `/home/kristina/desire-directory`

I know `sys.path[0]` from `sys`. But I don't want to parse `sys.path[0]` resulting string. Is there any another way to get parent of current directory in Python?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

#### Using os.path

To *get the parent directory of the directory containing the script* (regardless of the current working directory), you'll need to use `__file__`.

Inside the script use [`os.path.abspath(__file__)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to obtain the absolute path of the script, and call [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) twice:

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
d = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))) # /home/kristina/desire-directory
```

Basically, you can walk up the directory tree by calling `os.path.dirname` as many times as needed. Example:

```
In [4]: from os.path import dirname

In [5]: dirname('/home/kristina/desire-directory/scripts/script.py')
Out[5]: '/home/kristina/desire-directory/scripts'

In [6]: dirname(dirname('/home/kristina/desire-directory/scripts/script.py'))
Out[6]: '/home/kristina/desire-directory'
```

If you want to *get the parent directory of the current working directory*, use [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd):

```
import os
d = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
```

#### Using pathlib

You could also use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module (available in Python 3.4 or newer).

Each `pathlib.Path` instance have the `parent` attribute referring to the parent directory, as well as the `parents` attribute, which is a list of ancestors of the path. [`Path.resolve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) may be used to obtain the absolute path. It also resolves all symlinks, but you may use `Path.absolute` instead if that isn't a desired behaviour.

`Path(__file__)` and `Path()` represent the script path and the current working directory respectively, therefore in order to *get the parent directory of the script directory* (regardless of the current working directory) you would use

```
from pathlib import Path
# `path.parents[1]` is the same as `path.parent.parent`
d = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1] # Path('/home/kristina/desire-directory')
```

and to *get the parent directory of the current working directory*

```
from pathlib import Path
d = Path().resolve().parent
```

Note that `d` is a `Path` instance, which isn't always handy. You can convert it to `str` easily when you need it:

```
In [15]: str(d)
Out[15]: '/home/kristina/desire-directory'
```

Comment: `Path(__file__).resolve().parent` -> `Path(".").resolve()`. This also works when there isn't a `__file__` because you started in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: if script is in `/scripts` folder, like` /home/kristina/desire-directory/scripts/myScript.py` the first solution will not return the desired directory, it will return `/scripts` instead

Comment: all others `os.blabla` isn't work for me but this solution. Many many thanks!

Comment: `from pathlib import Path`
`BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent`, this works for me

Answer (score 25):

Use `Path.parent` from the `pathlib` module:

```
from pathlib import Path

# ...

Path(__file__).parent
```

You can use multiple calls to `parent` to go further in the path:

```
Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me (I am on Ubuntu):

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import os
current_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
parent_of_parent_dir = os.path.join(current_file, '../../')
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is what worked:

```
from os import path
path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__))
```

You get the current directory using the current file as a reference, and then call the `path.dirname` again to get the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

`'..'` returns parent of current directory.

```
import os
os.chdir('..')
```

Now your current directory will be `/home/kristina/desire-directory`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use`../your_script_name.py`
For example suppose the path to your python script is `trading system/trading strategies/ts1.py`. To refer to `volume.csv` located in `trading system/data/`. You simply need to refer to it as `../data/volume.csv`

Answer (score 0):

> import os def parent_directory():    # Create a relative path to the
> parent     # of the current working directory
> path = os.getcwd()
> parent = os.path.dirname(path)
>
> ```
> relative_parent = os.path.join(path, parent)
>
> # Return the absolute path of the parent directory
> return relative_parent
> ```
>
> print(parent_directory())

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
import sys
from os.path import dirname, abspath

d = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
print(d)
path1 = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
print(path1)
path = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0]
print(path)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from os.path import dirname
from os.path import abspath

def get_file_parent_dir_path():
    """return the path of the parent directory of current file's directory """
    current_dir_path = dirname(abspath(__file__))
    path_sep = os.path.sep
    components = current_dir_path.split(path_sep)
    return path_sep.join(components[:-1])
```